# Different Between this two method in jsp page

Tags: java

What is the difference between:

```
this.log("log message");
```

and

```
((HttpServlet)page).log("anothermessage");
```

?

Comment: what `this` represents in JSP? are you using **Scriplet**?

Comment: `JspServlet` extends `HttpServlet`. So there is no difference. The `log()` method is defined in `GenericServlet` that is super class of both.

Comment: yes i am using scriplet and ((HttpServlet)page).log is a implicit method and this.log is userdefine method.      I want to know the difference between them

Comment: Here `page` represents `JspServlet` that is equivalent to `this` in jsp.

Comment: why we need to typecast ((HttpServlet)page).log("anothermessage");

Comment: Both are same and you don't need to up-cast it before method call.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the generated Servlet from JSP then you will find that `this` and `page` both are same. Here `page` is and [implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) in JSP.

Generate Servlet code from JSP:

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    PageContext pageContext = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    ServletContext application = null;
    ServletConfig config = null;
    JspWriter out = null;
    Object page = this;         // page and this are same
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;
    ...
```

---

The `log()` method is defined in `GenericServlet`. Here is the tomcat(apache) specific implementation of generated Servlet from JSP:

```
javax.servlet.GenericServlet
   extended byjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
      extended byorg.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
```

So `this.log("log message")` is equivalent to `((HttpServlet)page).log("anothermessage")`